# Circular phylogeny names cut

Tags: r, plot, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm trying to place a phylogeny at the middle of a composite plot. I however fail to find the proper setting for this, as either the names on top&bottom, or the names on left and right are cut.
The only solution I found is reducing cex (size of taxa name), but then it looks really silly, because the taxa names are minute.

Simple reproducible example:

`library(ape)`
`par(fig=c(0.25, 0.75, 0.25,0.75))`
`data(bird.orders)`
`plot(bird.orders, type = "fan", use.edge.length = T)`

Any ideas how to solve this? It would be ideal if I could scale down the branch length part of the plot in comparison to taxa name.

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454927/how-can-i-adjust-the-position-of-tip-labels-relative-to-tree-tips-on-a-phylogene

Answer (score 1):

The `xpd` graphical parameter allows text to plot outside a clipping area.  Try `par(xpd = NA)`:

```r
library(ape)
par(fig=c(0.25, 0.75, 0.25,0.75), xpd = NA)
data(bird.orders)
plot(bird.orders, type = "fan", use.edge.length = T)
```

[image: Output]

You can change the ratio of text size to edge lengths using the `cex` parameter and enlarging the `fig` area, as you allude to you your question.